# Regex not giving proper result in python

Tags: python, regex

I have to search string with format `aaa.aaa.aaa. ...... n times`, **"a"** can be any alphanumeric or special char.

For the pattern I made `^.{3}(\..{3})*` regex

**^.{3}** => Starting first 3 chars can be any

**(\..{3})*** => Next should be dot and followed by 3 any chars ntimes (0 or more times repetitions)

The issue is regex pattern returns true if it matches first 3 chars and it ignores the optional condition. Is there any way to resolve the issue?

**Regex101:** https://regex101.com/r/KpI9VF/2

**Python Code:**

```
import re
import sys

regex_pattern = r"^.{3}(?:\..{3})*"

test_array = ["123.456.abc.def",
              "1123.456.abc.def",
              "123.125.528.256",
              "asd.asd.asd.asd",
              "123456789.2.2.2",
              "123.125.528.256",
              "123456789.2.2.2",
              "...............",
              "...",
              "`!@.#$%.^&*.()_",
              "1234.123.123.123",
              "123.123.123.1234",
              "...123.123.123.123..."
             ]

for test_string in test_array:
  match_res = re.match(regex_pattern, test_string) is not None
  print(test_string + " ==> " +str(match_res).lower())
```

**Output:**

```
123.456.abc.def ==> true
1123.456.abc.def ==> true
123.125.528.256 ==> true
asd.asd.asd.asd ==> true
123456789.2.2.2 ==> true
123.125.528.256 ==> true
123456789.2.2.2 ==> true
............... ==> true
... ==> true
`!@.#$%.^&*.()_ ==> true
1234.123.123.123 ==> true
123.123.123.1234 ==> true
...123.123.123.123... ==> true
```

**Expected Output**

```
123.456.abc.def     true
1123.456.abc.def    false
123.125.528.256     true
asd.asd.asd.asd     true
123456789.2.2.2     false
123.125.528.256     true
123456789.2.2.2     false
...............     true
...         false
`!@.#$%.^&*.()_     true
1234.123.123.123    false
123.123.123.1234    false
...123.123.123.123...   false
```

Comment: Should you use `+` instead of `*`?

Comment: @Sraw Tried but `123.123.123.1234` failed. it should return false but its returning true

Comment: Well, if you want to match the whole string, then you should use `$` to represent the end of the string. `r"^.{3}(?:\..{3})+$"`

Comment: Also, @dahiya_boy is n greater than 1 or 0?

Comment: @Sraw Putting `$` is worked  irrespective of `+` or `*`. Can you pls explain when to `$` and whats its effect?

Comment: It is the anchor that indicates the end of the line.

Comment: @nizarcan Agrred, but if I dont write $ then its also understandable that the pattern should end with 3 chars with were followed by dot(.)

Comment: What about the case `...123.123.123.123...`?

Comment: Or `123.123.123.1234`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^.{3}(?:\..{3})+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dEnT1L/1).

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of string
- `.{3}` - any 3 chars other than line break chars
- `(?:\..{3})+` - **one or more** occurrences of

  - `\.` - a `.` char
  - `.{3}` - any 3 chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E.%7B3%7D(%3F%3A%5C..%7B3%7D)%2B%24):

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain how $ makes the difference? Its unclear for me.

Comment: @dahiya_boy `$` requires  the end of string position.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition you gave in the question, `...` should match with the pattern. And what you also need is a string ending anchor `$`.

I believe if you update your expression as `r"^.{3}(\..{3})*$"`(Also removed `?:`), it works as intended.

Comment: Did not "blindly copied" anything since our answers were as far from each other given the condition.(You provided an expression.). Was just trying to help, as I said the pattern you descibed matches with the expression I just wrote above, good luck.